# Evenly divide paragraphs vertically in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, paragraph

I am using the bootstrap grid to build a layout.
In this layout I have a page that displays questions and answers as a FAQ. I created one row with 3 columns of each 4 wide. I put paragraphs in them that contain the questions and answers. Now I have 13 of these paragraphs and a title div containing a logo and two headers.

Currently I'm using max height and padding on the divs to try to space them evenly but it's not working out everywhere and I am just curious to see if there is a more convenient way to divide these paragraphs since I think this is something that more people want to do.

So this is my current html;

```
<div class="row faq">
        <div class="col-lg-4 lefttop">
        <div class="faqtitle">
            </div></div>
</div>
```

And this is my current css;

```
.faqcontainer {
    margin-right:4%;
    margin-top:2%;
}

.faq {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:18px;
}

.faq h3 {
    font-size:22px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-weight:500;
}

.faq h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#ee7d2f;
}

.faq p {
    max-width:450px;
    min-height:130px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:15px;
    padding-top:30px;
}

.faq a {
    color:#598edf;
    background: none !important;
}

.faqtitle {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}

.faqtitle h2, h1 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.numbers {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#598edf;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:6px;
    font-weight:200;
}
.bigorange {
    color:#ee7d2f;
    font-size:70px;
    font-weight:800;
}

.orange {
    color:#ee7d2f;}
```

Now I tried looking into vertical-align auto but another question on stack showed this was not the way to go. Setting the same height and margin on everything is not possible either since some of the paragraphs are a little longer than other but this is compensated by the shorter paragraphs.

Could anyone give me a suggestion on a more convenient/better way to do this?

Comment: too big...can you create a fiddle for simplicity in understanding please???

Comment: I can't put it in a fiddle because it's built in bootstrap.. I have a version online here though; http://kellyvuijst.nl/FINAL/ it's the 'Informatie' section.

Comment: You can write a fiddle for bootstrap with bootply : http://bootply.com/new#

Comment: here is a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/p4RRV/, but we obviously missing some markup ...

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of `column-count: 3;`, http://jsfiddle.net/A6jC6/.

Comment: @JoshPowell, good one - but not so well supported in IE http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count

Comment: Yes that is due to IE being a terrible pile of garbage but does the OP need full IE support?

Comment: @davidkonrad That is because of bootstrap. ;) I made a bootply; http://bootply.com/101045

Comment: If you look carefully at the jsfiddle i posted, you will see it is a twitter bootstrap 3 fiddle ...

Comment: Yes but I did not know that it was possible to do that before so that is why the markup is missing, that is what I was trying to say. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need IE9 and below support then I would recommend this method.

`Column-count` is a great style to use when you want to make even columns.

Here is how I did this,

```
<div class="columnSplit">
            <p><span class="numbers">1</span><b>.. Konijntjes?</b> Wat begon als geintje voor een bedrijfsnaam liep al snel uit tot de start van een fantastisch avontuur. Krankzinnig? Wellicht. Marketingtechnisch handig? Het heeft z'n uitdagingen. Maar ach, je vergeet de naam niet snel.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">2</span><b>Onze diensten?</b> Kort gezegd; ICT dienstverlening met een stukje elektrotechniek als aanvulling. Of het nu gaat om dagelijks beheer of incidenteel ondersteuning, wij nemen de technische touwtjes uit handen. Naast de techniek leveren wij desgewenst hardware, software en licenties. Standaard platform ondersteuning voor: Apple, Linux en Microsoft. En vragen omtrent oudere platformen zoals NT4 zijn natuurlijk ook van harte welkom. Al een beheerder in dienst? Gebruik ons dan als aanvulling of vraagbaak. En de elektrotechniek? Dat is dé brug die eindeloze mogelijkheden biedt om systemen te koppelen met je omgeving.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">3</span> <b>Onze concept?</b> We doen het goed of we doen het niet. Geen grijze gebieden omtrent ondersteuning of beheer van het netwerk en alles daar omheen. Als wij iets niet kunnen dan leren wij het, simpel.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">4</span> <b>En de kosten?</b> Zonder vaste overeenkomst hanteren wij standaard € 65,- per uur. Natuurlijk staan wij open voor verdere onderhandeling. Verder is al het beheer onder een vaste overeenkomst volledig gedekt. Ben je een goed doel? Neem contact op, wij dragen graag een technisch steentje bij.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">5</span> <b>Doen jullie dan ook echt alles zelfstandig?</b> Uiteraard, Als de ruimte er is, zeker weten. Als onderdelen sneller, beter, goedkoper of zelfs gratis kunnen zullen we het zeker niet laten de zaken uit te besteden. Uiteraard houden wij de touwtjes in handen, het technisch geneuzel is immers ons ding.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">6</span> <b>Hebben jullie referenties?</b> Uiteraard. Let wel, wij lopen niet zomaar te koop met ons klantenbestand. Onze relaties en bovenal het vertrouwen is ons heilig, daarom hanteren wij standaard een geheimhoudingsplicht. Al met al geven onze openbare referenties een mooi beeld van de diversiteit en mogelijkheden.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">7</span> <b>Waarom ons?</b> Je huurt ons niet in omdat wij leuk kunnen programmeren of blindelings een configuratie in elkaar kunnen zetten. Onze kennis en producten helpen te besparen op tijd, geld, moeite en zenuwen. Wij maken onze geweldige klanten nog beter. En als wij iets niet goed doen, dan kost dat ons tijd. Niets meer, niets minder.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">8</span> <b>Ons motto?</b> Flexibiliteit is koning. Niets vervelenders dan complexe omgevingen en lastige vraagstukken met bijkomstige afhankelijkheden. Iets waar je als ondernemer niet mee verveeld wilt worden. Het gaat om oplossingen die helpen efficiënt te werken en continuïteit te waarborgen.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">9</span> <b>Hoe wij denken over ICT?</b> ICT draait om technische oplossingen, het vakgebied gaat echter verder dan techniek alleen. Het over de schutting gooien van allerlei softwarepakketten is dan ook niet onze doelstelling.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">10</span> <b>ICT diensten en software ontwikkeling is helder, maar waarom ruimtevaart?</b> Het raakvlak tussen ICT en het creëren van een commercieel interplanetair netwerk ligt dichter bij elkaar dan je wellicht denkt. Internet in de ruimte, communicatie tussen Aarde, Maan, Mars en alles daar tussenin.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">11</span> <b>Dat is er toch al lang?</b> Jazeker, alleen bieden de huidige technieken flink wat beperkingen. En zeg nu zelf; als je straks op Mars bent wil je toch ook zonder zorgen bellen met het thuisfront of de nieuwste filmpjes op internet kunnen bekijken?</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">12</span> <b>Klinkt spannend, wanneer is het klaar?</b> Wij zijn druk bezig met het plan de campagne en de bouw van het eerste prototype om daarna te werken aan een algehele productie en uitrol.</p>
            <p><span class="numbers">13</span> <b>Zijn er nog meer verrassingen?</b> Meer van onze avonturen kun je lezen op ons blog via <a href="http://blog.konijntjes.nl">blog.konijntjes.nl</a></p>
</div>
```

I am putting only the `p` content inside of this parent. The `h1` and other content seem to get all screwy with the column count so only put what you want to be a column into the parent.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TL7a3/1/) to play with. You will need to do some extra styling because the margin/padding on the `p` tags is causing some slight issues.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I do not need support for IE9 or below.

Comment: Not to many people need that anymore. :] Best of luck in your design mate!

Comment: well, IE8 is still the most used IE out there -> http://www.winbeta.org/news/ie10-second-most-popular-internet-explorer-version-ie8-still-number-one ...But +1, great answer

Comment: Wow that is slightly depressing but at least IE 8 and IE9 aren't horrendous to work with like IE 6 and IE 7.